# Dual epub reader

Tags: applications, ebook-reader

I have started using my tablet for reading epubs and I have found a lot of different versions of the same book.

So, is there any application that allows me to compare, i.e. to see both versions in a split screen?

I thought it would be easy to find this because it is such a useful utility!

I have tried the 10 most used application for reading epubs and no single one allows me to do this.

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575). With the correct phrasing and details provided, you might try your luck at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185). As this one's really hard to find, I've made the exception of answering it, though.

Comment: PS: I've pinged our mods on both ends, asking if this question should be moved over to *Software Recs*. Hope that's fine with you. Not sure whether they migrate it, though, as SR is still in Beta (and thus no "official migration target").

Comment: Marc, if you wish to have your question moved to *Software Recommendations*, I've just got "green lights" from a mod over there (we'd need to apply some cosmetics to your question then, though). Up to you now to give it a go (or not).

Comment: Yes! Of course! I have corrected some minor grammar mistakes. I have no problem in moving the question, as you wish.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your updates! I've asked for "the move", so let's see whether it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's **EPUB3 Reader** available on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=it.angrydroids.epub3reader) and [Github](https://github.com/pettarin/epub3reader) (not on *Google Play* – though an app using the same package name exists there, it's not the same, but obviously based on the original developers engine; long story behind that, not fitting here). Its app description explicitely mentions this feature:

> - parallel texts (e.g., original text and its translation into another language).

Find [some screenshots here](https://github.com/pettarin/epub3reader/blob/master/SCREENSHOTS.md). Picking one example:

[image: EPUB3 Reader]

Looks exactly like what you're after.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much. I didn't knew about F-Droid, so double thank you!

Amazing help that you give.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! For some more background on F-Droid (and some other markets), you might wish to read [my article here](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android_markets_safe_to_use) (F-Droid and Aptoide have some apps which are not on Play; the article discusses their security measures, quite impressive). For this specific app, I already had some contact with the devs, which are quite responsive (it was a students project, the Profs answered me when I informed them of the "package name trouble" mentioned above).